# How do I rearrange a pandas dataframe, such that the second row index and all follwing are appended to the last column of first index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Let me illustrate my question,
let's assume  a data frame as below,**

| id | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dr Who | David Tenant |
| 2 | Dr Who | Matt Smith |

**I want it to be rearranged as below,**

| id | Question | Answer | id | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dr Who | David Tenant | 2 | Dr Who | Matt Smith |

**Any thoughtful discussion will be super helpful. At the moment I am not even sure where to start to address this problem.**

This might look strange, but it's due to a specific request made by a client and I am trying my best to help them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'    id': {0: 1, 1: 2},
 'Question': {0: 'Dr Who', 1: 'Dr Who'},
 'Answer': {0: 'David Tenant', 1: 'Matt Smith'}})
```

**Solution:**

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(1,-1), columns=['id', 'Question', 'Answer']*len(df))

    id  Question    Answer          id  Question    Answer
0   1   Dr Who      David Tenant    2   Dr Who      Matt Smith
```

Comment: Thanks, Allen, I will try this solution and let you know if it solved it for me!

Comment: Allen, thank you so much it worked perfectly for my df that had around 40000 rows and 33 columns. Much appreciate your help!